# Database query not respecting transactions

Tags: .net-core, dapper

I have a bit of code that I'm using to pull items from a database one at a time. On each get, it updates the status of the row to indicate that it has been retrieved so as to not retrieve the same row multiple times.

The below code is run from a backend service serving a Web API. Sometimes when multiple requests come in, it will return the same row (tasks with the same ID).

I was under the impression that having a transaction around it would mean that an update from one of the runs would preclude the row from being returned by a second query.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
public async Task<TaskDetail> GetTask()
{
    using (var db = new SqlConnection(""))
    {
        using (var tran = db.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {

                var sql = $@"
                    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
                        (SELECT TOP 150 t.*
                        FROM Task t
                        INNER JOIN TaskStatus ts ON t.Id = ts.TaskId AND ts.Status = @taskStatus) t
                    ORDER BY NEWID();";

                    var chosen = await db
                        .QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<TaskDetail>(
                        sql,
                        param: new
                        {
                            taskStatus = TaskStatusEnum.Ready
                        },
                        transaction: tran
                    );
                    if (chosen == null)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException();
                    }
                    var expiry = await db.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE TaskStatus SET Status = @status WHERE TaskId = @taskId", new {status = TaskStatusEnum.Done, taskId = chosen.TaskId}, tran);

                    tran.Commit();

                    return chosen;
                }
                catch
                {
                    tran.Rollback();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few wrong configurations can be the reason;

1- Check the SQL Server isolation level, be careful about dirty reads.
2- Be sure that you handle the error in web API properly, because especially transaction error is not displayed properly.
3- And, please remove t-sql from code :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. A few follow-ups. 1. What should the isolation level be? 2. The Web API doesn't throw an error when we see the issue. 3. Convention when using Dapper is to have the SQL within the code - matter of personal preference.

Comment: Isolation level is up to your project requirements, it is really hard to say specific one for this case, can be misleading. But you can google and can find the appropriate one, there is just four isolation level we have. Other option is Web API also can throw and error but a bit strange way please search WebFaultException, Dapper is one of the best ORM but if you manage very large objects, you can have performance problems like other ORMs. I wish it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Select query doesn't block rows data from other transactions, two select in different transaction will be performed at the same time. You can try to set a session id on the row and then select it.

**EDIT**: hope this help, when update is executed it should block the row for others transactions

```
public async Task<TaskDetail> GetTask()
{
    using (var db = new SqlConnection(""))
    {
        using (var tran = db.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {

            var mySessionId = Guid.NewGuid();

            var sql = $@"
                UPDATE TaskStatus SET Status = @status, SessionId = @mySessionId WHERE TaskId in 
                    (SELECT TOP 1
                    t.Id
                    FROM Task t
                    INNER JOIN TaskStatus ts ON t.Id = ts.TaskId AND ts.Status = @taskStatus ORDER BY NEWID());";

                await db
                .QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<TaskDetail>(
                    sql,
                    param: new
                    {
                        taskStatus = TaskStatusEnum.Ready
                        status = TaskStatusEnum.InProgress,
                        mySessionId = mySessionId
                    },
                    transaction: tran
                );


                var sql = $@"
                    SELECT TOP 150 t.*
                    FROM Task t
                    INNER JOIN TaskStatus ts ON t.Id = ts.TaskId AND ts.Status = @taskStatus
                    WHERE ts.SessionId = @mySessionId;";

                    var chosen = await db
                        .QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<TaskDetail>(
                        sql,
                        param: new
                        {
                            taskStatus = TaskStatusEnum.InProgress,
                            mySessionId = mySessionId
                        },
                        transaction: tran
                    );
                if (chosen == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
                var expiry = await db.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE TaskStatus SET Status = @status WHERE TaskId = @taskId", new {status = TaskStatusEnum.Done, taskId = chosen.TaskId}, tran);

                tran.Commit();

                return chosen;
            }
            catch
            {
                tran.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you explain your solution further? I don't understand.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting solution.